# Summarization of text document (Multi document i.e News) By finding events

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, text-mining, summarization

Respected Sir, Mem

I Wants to summarizing of text document (any unstructured i.e news Data). My first target is to find important events in this given text data and next(2nd step) based on these events i will select some important events (by some methods).

1. Please tell me some paper to find EVENTS from Text.(If LATEST then will be better)
2. Please tell me some paper which finding EVENTS using MACHINE LEARNING or SOFT COMPUTING.

THANK YOU

chandrtech15@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.com/cse?cx=011664571474657673452%3A4w9swzkcxiy&cof=FORID%3A0&q=event+extraction#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=event%20extraction&gsc.page=1 This is a list of a google search over the ACL (Association for Computational Linguistics) anthology. There should be many relevant papers on the list.